# In France, is it legal to practice target shooting on your own land?

Tags: is-x-legal, france, firearms

I can find a lot of information about hunting on your own land, and my land would qualify for that. However, I don't have a hunting license and I'm in fact more interested in target practice / sport shooting. I do of course have a sport shooting license and legally registered weapons.

My land does have a good hill as backdrop and it's large enough and over 150 meter away from the nearest dwelling. In the country of France, is it legal to practice target shooting on my own land, or only at an official gun range?

Comment: Probably worth asking: What if people could be in gun range legally? What if people could be in gun range illegally? What if you hurt someone?

Comment: I cannot answer on French law, but what happens if you accidentally shoot over that 'good' hill? Even shotgun pellets can travel several hundred meters, and rifle rounds can travel for several miles (not aimed, just random scatter). On a practical matter, **don't** do that without a proper range.

Answer (score 2):

### Not with that license

Your post makes clear that you have a sports license, not a hunting license. In that case, it was delivered in accordance with [R312-40 of the *code de la sécurité intérieure*](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000025503132/LEGISCTA000029655171):

> Peuvent être autorisés pour la pratique du tir sportif à acquérir et à détenir des armes, munitions et leurs éléments (...):
>
> 1° Les associations sportives agréées (...)
>
> 2° Les personnes majeures (...)
>
> **Sauf dans le cadre des compétitions internationales, ces armes ne peuvent être utilisées que dans les stands de tir des associations mentionnées au 1° du présent article.**

> A license to acquire and own arms, ammunitions and related elements (...), can be granted to:
>
> 1° Accredited sports associations (...)
>
> 2° People older than 18 (...)
>
> **Except within the framework of international competitions, those weapons can only be used in shooting ranges of associations mentioned at 1°.**